# year/month/day/hour/minute/second filters in django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've defined a django-rest filter like this:

```
created_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(
    lookup_type=["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second", "lt", "lte", "gt", "gte"])
```

this url does a proper query: created_date < 2015-05-01:

http://localhost:8000/path/objects/?created_date__lt=2015-05-01

the same thing works with gt for: created_date > 2015-05-01:

http://localhost:8000/path/objects/?created_date__gt=2015-05-01

this url does a proper query: created_date > 2015-05-01

However, when I try to query on year:

http://localhost:8000/path/objects/?created_date__year=2015

I get

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

I also tried

http://localhost:8000/path/objects/?created_date__year=2015-05-01

and I get the same error. Any idea how to get the year/month/day/hour/minute/second filters working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTimeFilter` filter converts input value to datetime, so `created_date__year` is compared to datetime and this is wrong. It has to be compared with `int`.

Solution 1:

Add another filter for same field:

```
created_date_part = django_filters.NumberFilter(
    name='created_date',
    lookup_type=["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"])
```

However you need to create another name for this field.

Solution 2:

Write custom filter that will inherit `CharFilter` and do all validation by itself.